# Python: KeyError with form.getfirst

Tags: python, dtml

I have a dtml page, which calls a function, with this code:

```
<dtml-var public_blast(form.getfirst('job_ID'))>
```

But i get a key error? stating `KeyError: "public_blast(form.getfirst('job_ID'))"`. I can see the job_ID variable at the top of the page. So i know it is being passed to the URL.

I cant see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a very long time since I did any DTML, but I don't think you can call Python functions directly like that inside a DTML tag.

Instead I think you need to use the `expr` attribute:

```
<dtml-var expr="public_blast(form.getfirst('job_ID'))">
```

Comment: Just get a NameError: Name form is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try `<dtml-var "REQUEST['job_ID']">`