# Python: Obtain a URL

Tags: python, zope, dtml

Because I cant get this working: [Python: KeyError with form.getfirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250572/python-keyerror-with-form-getfirst)

I have an alternative option, I have a function in DTML which needs to obtain a URL:

For example if the dtml webpage is located at

> www.blah.com/foo/foo2?variable=55

How would i obtain the URL of this page using a python function?

The function is called by:

```
<dtml-var test>
```

The syntax for "test" is rite, the Zope documentation says so.

Comment: What?  "http://" + "www.blah.com/foo/foo2?variable=55" is a URL.  What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

for: http://www.blah.com/foo/foo2?job_ID=55555&test=1

`<dtml-var URL>` = http://www.blah.com/foo/foo2

`<dtml-var QUERY_STRING>` = job_ID=55555&test=1

`<dtml-var "REQUEST['job_ID']">` = 55555

See: http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/REQUESTX