# Python: obtain the url?

Tags: python, zope

Whats the simpliest way to obtain the URL of the webpage you are currently on?

For example if i have a python function and i call it from within a webpage, whats the best way to obtain the URL. What maybe an easier question how is how do you obtain the variables passed within the URL i.e. after the "?"

I've tried calling:

```
def return_query(self):
    self.request.url
```

I have also tried

```
def return_query2(self):
    self.request.query_string
```

But i get a attrbiute error for request

Comment: What means 'from within webpage'? Are you using CGI (if so, check `os.environ`)? What are you passing as `self` to `return_query`? What 'being on the webpage' means?  How the heck are we supposed to answer that question, knowing exactly nothing about your code? ;)

Comment: How you get the current URL depends on what web framework you are using.  Give us some more details.

Comment: I'm using dtml webpage to call the function

Comment: Are you using Zope then?

Comment: dup?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251020/python-obtain-a-url

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
def return_query(self):
    return self.request.URL
```

Python is case-sensitive.

Note that I have not tried this myself, but after looking at the documentation, I would hazard a guess that your only problem is the case of `URL` - make sure it is all capitals and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Zope question?  context.absolute_url() might come close to what the original questioner intended.